# Chosen.js dynamically populate dropdown on keyup

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I've almost successfully implemented Chosen.js on a dropdown. My code is here:

```
$('#skills_chosen').on('change', function(){
    var items="";
    var typedOpt = $('#skills_chosen').val();
    $.getJSON("php/skillList.php", {term:typedOpt}, function(skillList){
    $.each(skillList,function(index,item) 
    {
      items+="<option value='"+item.skill+"'>"+item.skill+"</option>";
    });
    $("#skills").append(items); 
    $('.chzn-select').trigger("chosen:updated");
    });

});
```

I'm having a slight issue. The dropdown fires the ajax call only after the select box has lost focus, and the options are not available until after the select box regains focus. This is obviously not very user friendly.

I've tried to alter the event trigger to

```
$('#skills_chosen').on('keyup', function(){
```

as well as keydown, keypress. These all work first time but they empty the text area so only one character can be typed. It's driving me mad.

I've also tried wrapping the ajax call to populate select box on page load, pre-populating the select options. This stops the select options box working. If I try to retain what is kept in the "text field" after the select options update, it doesn't make a difference.

What have I done wrong and how can I get this to work the first time the select box gets focus and the user starts typing?

Comment: you don't have html in your page?

Comment: I have taken the script out of the page so I don't post too much code... The select box works in principle. It only works once you click, type, then click elsewhere on the page, return to the select box and start typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about the click event?

```
    $('#skills_chosen').on('click change', function(){
        var items="";
        var typedOpt = $('#skills_chosen').val();
        $.getJSON("php/skillList.php", {term:typedOpt}, function(skillList){
        $.each(skillList,function(index,item) 
        {
          items+="<option value='"+item.skill+"'>"+item.skill+"</option>";
        });
        $("#skills").append(items); 
        $('.chzn-select').trigger("chosen:updated");
        });

    }) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#skills_chosen').on('click change', function(){
    var items="";
    var typedOpt = $('#skills_chosen').val();
    $.getJSON("php/skillList.php", {term:typedOpt}, function(skillList){
    $.each(skillList,function(index,item) 
    {
      items+="<option value='"+item.skill+"'>"+item.skill+"</option>";
    });
    $("#skills").append(items); 
    $('.chzn-select').trigger("chosen:updated");
    });

}) ;
```

@madalin ivascu this worked a treat, thank you :)